# How to get Mediacorp TV guide Source

Tags: android

I am developing TV guide apps on Android mobile. I have an issue, anybody know where to get mediacorp tv guide source from? Do they provide an API/SDK so that we can retrieve the information.

Advice

Answer (score 0):

As Mediacorp provides dedicated web page to display TV guide, you can read&parse the content programmatically as long as they don't change the page frequently.

URL : http://www2.mediacorp.com.sg/cgi-bin/tvguide/tvguide_channel.asp?channel=tcs5

Try to use HttpClient to query from above link.

Comment: Thank you very much! Using the httpClient to get the format of the website then future scale down to the structure we need.

Comment: Please add reputation to my answer if it's helpful. Thanks!